# How to change parent props.relay.variables from child component?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, graphql, relayjs

I have a collection container and offset pagination container in my React + Relay Classic app. Pagination must be composable, because I can have several collections for using this pagination container.

My parent container contain all pagination variables (in my case it is limit and offset) because they must exist there for proper fetch. So, when I click in pagination container next page, click handler must setVariables of parent container.

At this moment I'm using workaround and send relay.variables and relay.setVariables to pagination container via props with another names (parentRelayVariables and setParentVariables) and still seek for a best solution.

```
class PostsPagination extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    posts: PropTypes.shape({
      pageInfo: PropTypes.shape({
        hasNextPage: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      }).isRequired,
      totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }),
    setParentRelayVariables: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    parentRelayVariables: PropTypes.shape({
      offset: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
    left: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };

  renderFirstPage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.setParentRelayVariables({ offset: 0 });
  }

  renderNextPage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.setParentRelayVariables({
      offset: this.props.parentRelayVariables.offset + 5,
    });
  }

  renderAnotherPage(e, page) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.setParentRelayVariables({
      offset: (page - 1) * 5,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const currentPage = this.props.parentRelayVariables.offset
      ? (this.props.parentRelayVariables.offset / 5) + 1
      : 1;

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(this.props.posts.totalCount / 5);

    const pages = createPagesArray(currentPage, totalPages);

    return (<div className="row paginate">
      <ul>
        <li key="first">
          <a
            className={this.props.parentRelayVariables.offset ? '' : 'inactive'}
            href=""
            role="button"
            onClick={e => this.renderFirstPage(e)}
          >В начало</a>
        </li>
        {pages.map(page => <li key={page}>
          <a
            className={page === currentPage ? 'active' : ''}
            href=""
            role="button"
            onClick={e => this.renderAnotherPage(e, page)}
          >
            {page}
          </a>
        </li>)}
        <li key="last">
          <a
            href=""
            className={this.props.posts.pageInfo.hasNextPage ? '' : 'inactive'}
            role="button"
            onClick={e => this.renderNextPage(e)}
          >
            Далее
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>);
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(PostsPagination, {
  fragments: {
    posts: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on PostConnection {
            pageInfo {
                hasNextPage,
            },
            totalCount
        },
    `,
  },
});
```

Comment: You mention Relay Classic, but then you mention pagination containers. Just to be clear: you *are* on Classic, right? Only Modern has the concept of a "pagination container" as such; Classic just has containers. And what do you mean about "all pagination variables ... must exist there for proper fetch"?

Comment: @wincent Thanks, Greg, for your time! My app using Relay Classic, sry for using term "Pagination container", I wanted to say Pagination Component, my bad. I've expanded question with part of code.